# How to remove Laravel default Strict-Transport-Security?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project with Laravel, Inertia. There is have `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=300; includeSubDomains; preload` default from Laravel Response Header. But i want to setting max-age to 12 months with .htaccess, like this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But now, there is have 2 Strict-Transport-Security, one from default, and one from htaccess settings

[image]

Because i have the main problem with HSTS, i think max-age is too low, so my laravel return error 419 on shared hosting production mode.

I have try to make custom middleware for this, and add to Kernel.php but the Strict-Transport-Security is not added.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer from here](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/laravel-http-strict-transport-security-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/)

Create `app/Http/Middleware/HSTS.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HSTS
{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->header('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age= 31536000; includeSubdomains');

        return $response;
    }

}
```

Add to Kernel (`app/Http/Kernel.php`)

```
protected $middleware = [
        // other existing middleware
        \App\Http\Middleware\HSTS::class
];
```

Comment: I have tried it sir, but i see console log network, there is still have ```Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=300``` only, not replaced default or add new.

Comment: I have just tried on a project and it works: `strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains`

Do you have any other middleware?

Comment: yes, i have, but the other middleware is default from Laravel and not for HSTS

Comment: Is the project on GitHub?

Comment: In fact I have just rechecked. Default Laravel does not set this header at all. Something else you have must be adding it.

Comment: here is my kernel.php middleware: https://ibb.co/FhM4PZD i have tried before, and i comment it because its not working

Comment: If you find in all files `strict-transport-security` does anything appear? Could your webhost be adding it?

Comment: nothing except HSTS middleware before.

Yes the devOps tell me that they are added HSTS for the hosting. before he add this HSTS, its all running well.

Comment: I think if your hosting is adding it then no matter what you do it will be ignored.

Comment: hmm maybe. But i wonder why my Laravel Inertia cant work well with HSTS enabled

Comment: Actually he say that my Laravel is still access with Http, but i think i have redirect to https in cpanel settings, install SSL, but its still not working

Comment: On the link in the answer I have there is also a redirect to https middleware.

Comment: what ```php artisan``` i should run after follow that tutorial? Because i have follow that, but there is no effect

Comment: You shouldn't need to run any, unless you decide to use the package option.

Comment: i will make sure again now, that i follow the tutorial correctly

Comment: Oh ya, can you show me your .env, and session.php sir? Please. Maybe i have wrong setting for that, specialy for SESSION_DOMAIN, COOKIES, http_only, etc

Comment: My `session.php` is unchanged from default Laravel session.php. The whole project is very new so most files are default to be honest.

My suggestion would be to deploy a fresh Laravel project on the same host/server. Try the above, if it still doesn't work then you devOps are enforcing the policy and you should speak to them.

Comment: ok sir. But the fact is, if i make a POST request from Postman to ```https://mywebsite.com/login``` it will error 419, but if i POST to ```http://mywebsite.com/login``` it will 200 OK. Do you know why this different sir?

Comment: Can you access your site at `https://mywebsite.com/` or does it redirect to `http://mywebsite.com/`

Comment: if i access the website at ```http://mywebsite.com/```, it will redirect to ```https```

Comment: i have other hosting without HSTS enabled, and i upload there, its work normally.